# How to write to a file in a googletest test case with bazel test?

Tags: bazel

I have a simple Bazel C++ project with the following directory layout:

```
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
├── file_test.cc
```

WORKSPACE:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
  name = "gtest",
  url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.10.0.tar.gz",
  sha256 = "9dc9157a9a1551ec7a7e43daea9a694a0bb5fb8bec81235d8a1e6ef64c716dcb",
  strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.10.0",
)
```

BUILD:

```
cc_test(
  name = "file_test",
  srcs = ["file_test.cc"],
  deps = [
    "@gtest//:gtest",
    "@gtest//:gtest_main",
  ],
)
```

file_test.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using namespace std;

TEST(File, Write) {
  cout << "Running..." << endl;
  ofstream out("foo", ios_base::app);
  out << "Go\n";
}
```

After running `bazelisk test`, `foo` is not created in the current working directory.

```
$ bazelisk test :file_test --test_output=all --cache_test_results=no
$ cat foo
cat: foo: No such file or directory
```

However, after running the built result, `foo` is created with the expected content.

```
$ bazel-bin/file_test
$ cat foo
Go
```

I am using the following Bazel through Bazelisk macOS 10.15.5.

```
$ bazelisk version
Bazelisk version: v1.7.5
Build label: 4.1.0
Build target: bazel-out/darwin-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Fri May 21 11:16:55 2021 (1621595815)
Build timestamp: 1621595815
Build timestamp as int: 1621595815
```

It seems that [Bazel Sandboxing](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/sandboxing.html) is the cause of file creation failure.

Is there a way to write the `foo` file with `bazel test`? Or if foo is created elsewhere, where can I find it?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do it with `bazel test`, because tests have to be hermetic. But you can use a test target to generate files using `bazel run`, see [example from python rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/1dc8ed9b1944c14893d21afb1dc72b6b723450fa/python/pip_install/pip_compile.py#L32): there is a env variable check, which dispatch different actions based on invocation type

Answer (score 0):

Your file should be in the folder that is outputted by `bazel info bazel-bin`. There should be a folder named `CC_TEST_TARGET_NAME.runfiles`. This folder should reflect our workspace structure.

`foo` fill never be created in your current source working directory. Tests run always "hermetic" and are [restricted in the access to the filesystem](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/test-encyclopedia.html#test-interaction-with-the-filesystem).

BTW: `copts = ["-Iexternal/gtest/include"]` is not needed

Comment: Remove copts as you suggested. But `CC_TEST_TARGET_NAME.runfiles` does not contain the `foo` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `---sandbox_debug` option when running `bazelisk test`.

After Bazel terimnates, use `bazelisk info` to get `output_base`. Then use `find ${output_base} -name foo` can find the file.